# Scala Play Slick Connection multiple Schema

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

this is my code 
Application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=param
slick.dbs.default.db.password="xxxx"

slick.dbs.default.driver="com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=param2
slick.dbs.default.db.password="xxxx"
```

how to connect multiple schema scala play slick oracle ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `slick.dbs.default.*`, you configurate your default schema. 
If you want to have multiple database connections, you can declare named databases.

Try to use something like this in your configuration:

```
oracle2.driver="com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver$"
oracle2.db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
oracle2.db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX"
oracle2.db.user=param2
oracle2.db.password="xxxx"
```

By default, the default database connection is used. If you'd like to use your other databases, in this case **oracle2**, you can inject them using the `NamedDatabase` annotation.

`@NamedDatabase("oracle2") override protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider`

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/basic
this demo is good, uses play 2.5.x and slick 3.x